# How use IChangeToken to expire a token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I wont to change a Token when DbContext.SaveChange() method called and ChangeTracker has change:

```
public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
    if (SettingChanged() == true)
    {

    }

    return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
}
```

and my DbChangeToken calss:

```
public class DbChangeToken : IChangeToken
{
   private DateTime _lastModified;
   private DateTime _lastRequested; 

    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get
        {
            var result = _lastModified >= _lastRequested;
            _lastRequested = DateTime.Now;

            return result;
        }
    }

    public bool ActiveChangeCallbacks => true;

    public IDisposable RegisterChangeCallback(Action<object> callback, object state) => EmptyDisposable.Instance;

}
```

my target is that change _lastModified every time SaveChange Method called.